# Project Euler #10 with Python, Numpy sum summing incorrectly

Tags: python, primes

[Project Euler #10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10)

I know this question has been asked, but I am having trouble finding out why I am getting the wrong answer, and the other posts about this have not been helpful to me.  The code is to find the sum of the prime numbers below 2,000,000.

```
import math
import numpy as np

def sum_primes(limit):      
    potential = 2
    primes = [potential]
    potential += 1
    primes.append(potential)

    while potential < limit:
        potential+=2
        test = True
        sqrt_potential = math.sqrt(potential)
        for a in primes:
            if a > sqrt_potential:
                break
            if potential%a == 0:
                test = False
                break
        if test and potential <= limit:
            primes.append(potential)

    print np.sum(primes)
    return
```

It appears that I am hitting all the primes but for some reason the sum isn't coming out correctly.  Anyone see a problem here?

Here is some output I am getting:

```
>>> sum_primes(20000)
21171191
>>> sum_primes(200000)
1709600813
>>> sum_primes(2000000)
1179908154
```

Comment: What are you getting and what should you be getting?

Comment: Can you provide us with the sum you get with the code above?

Comment: Does `np.sum` work the same as the built-in function `sum`? Because when I replace it, I get the correct answer.

Comment: Using the code from the OP and the Sieve mentioned below, I'm getting the same answer for primes up to 100,000 -- 454,396,537. I also tried it using a numpy array instead of a list and get the same thing.

Comment: Use the search box for "sieve of Eratosthenes", there is even a tag category here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes?sort=votes&pageSize=30, to find extensive discussions on efficient implementations.

Comment: Hey guys, I am very appreciative of all the answers and the more efficient implementations of my code.  However, I am interested to know what is causing the error with this particular snippet of code.

Comment: the answer by Aaron Hall shows the reason: it's an Int wrap-around. Evidently, your calculation is done with 32-bit ints. For some reason. :)

Comment: It's done with 32-bit ints because the OP is using `np.sum` for some reason, and it's coercing to `np.int32`.  If the OP uses `sum` instead of `np.sum`, it should work -- `numpy` doesn't natively support arbitrary-precision integer types, and can only use Python's standard arbitrary-precision `int` with `dtype=object`.

Comment: @WillNess thanks for pointing that out, I did post the full analysis. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave a fairly naive implementation on this, the last iteration took a while to return results.

```
def return_primes(upto=100):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, upto+1):
        if not any(not i % p for p in primes):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

And usage:

```
>>> sum(return_primes(upto=20000))
21171191
>>> sum(return_primes(upto=200000))
1709600813
>>> sum(return_primes(upto=2000000))
142913828922
```

Here's another implementation using the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def return_primes(upto=100):
    primes = []
    sieve = set()
    for i in range(2, upto+1):
        if i not in sieve:
            primes.append(i)
            sieve.update(range(i, upto+1, i))
    return primes
```

This is *much* faster, running in about a second or two, compared to minutes for the above:

```
>>> sum(return_primes(200000))
1709600813
>>> sum(return_primes(2000000))
142913828922
```

---

To attempt to better diagnose your problem with this information, we see that

```
>>> 142913828922 % 2**32
1179908154
```

Which (thank you Will Ness) leads one to conclude that you're summing with 32bit integers. If we change your code to the following:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def sum_primes(limit):      
    potential = 2
    primes = [potential]
    potential += 1
    primes.append(potential)
    while potential < limit:
        potential+=2
        test = True
        sqrt_potential = math.sqrt(potential)
        for a in primes:
            if a > sqrt_potential:
                break
            if potential%a == 0:
                test = False
                break
        if test and potential <= limit:
            primes.append(potential)
    print np.sum(primes, dtype=np.int64)
    return
```

then you should get the correct output.

And I do replicate your behavior if I instead use:

```
    print np.sum(primes, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you just posted another implementation.

Comment: Sometimes questioners find it helpful to look at a different way of solving their problem, if intractable. I recommend upvoting the other guy. I did.

Comment: you actually do provide an answer here: ``142913828922 `mod` (2^32) == 1179908154``. :)

Comment: Not sure why it would default to 32 bit thought. Maybe an older implementation? His code worked the way it was written for me.

Comment: was it on a 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 2):

In the initialization section of your script, you set `potential = 3`. Then the first statement in the while loop increments potential to 5. You never consider 3 as a potential prime. Fix it by setting `potential -= 1` in the initialization section of your script.

A better algorithm uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def sumPrimes(n):
    b, p, sum = [True] * (n+1), 2, 0
    for p in xrange(2, n+1):
        if b[p]:
            sum += p
            for i in xrange(p, n+1, p):
                b[i] = False
    return sum
```

If you're going to be doing the prime-number problems at Project Euler, you might want to read  [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Comment: _"You never consider 3 as a potential prime."_ You're right that the prime testing in the `while` loop never executes on three, but `primes` still contains `3` because he manually appends it in the initialization section, just before setting `limit`. So if the OP is getting a wrong answer, it's not for lack of a three. (PS. good recommendation on the Sieve)

Comment: Oh. I missed that. The dyslexia is strong dotay. Sorry. In any event, the Sieve of Eratosthenes, not trial division, is a better algorithm for this problem.